# Javascript separating text from anchor tags

Tags: javascript, regex, tags, anchor

I am facing difficulties in generalizing a string using REGEX in javascript.
I have a string which contains a couple of anchor tags, containing text that can be anything like:

```
<b> text <a href="javascript:opendynamicurlwindow('http://www.google.com', '', '', '', '','no')">www.google.com< /a ><abc><a href="javascript:opendynamicurlwindow( 'http://www.flipkart.com', '', '', '', '','no')" >www.flipkart.com</a></b>
```

I need to convert this text to html compatible values excepting anchor tags i.e.

```
 1. <b> text should be encoded as &lt;b&gt; text
 2. <abc> should be encoded as &lt;abc&gt; text 
 3. </a> should be encoded as &lt;/a&gt; text
```

I am having troubles in seperating the text and anchor tags so that i can process them correctly.
I have tried regex : (]*>+.*<+.*/a>) but matching is not working for multiple urls.

Comment: Isn't this: `$('<div />').text("<b>http://www.google.com<br/>www.google.com<abc>http://www.flipkart.com<a>www.flipkart.com</a>").html()` works? For what want you to save your urls unencoded?

Comment: its a comment field. So I have to leave the links as they are and have to display the text for confirmation before saving.

Comment: I add code to my answer

Answer (score 0):

One some tricky way to js-side `htmlencode` is:

```
var html = '<h1>Your <a href="http://google.com">html</a></h1>';
$('<div />').text(html).html()
```

Other way is direct replacing:

```
html
  .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
  .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
  .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
  .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
  .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
```

If you want to correct parse html text, you should use DOM parsers.
But in your case may works simple code below:

```
var anchorreg = /<a\s+[^>]+>(.*?)<\/a>/g;
var links = s.match(anchorreg);
var res = s.replace(anchorreg, '#anchor#');
res = htmlencode(res); // where htmlencode is one of methods above
for(var i=0;i<links.length;i++) res = res.replace('#anchor#', links[i])
console.log(res);
```